# How to do index match on more than 1 conditions in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following where I want to return the value of a search based on the month, however, there could be repeated month numbers in different years.

For example:
[image]

My current index match formula is:

```
=INDEX($E$8:$E$22,MATCH(I$2,$C$8:$C$22,0))
```

Please advise if it is possible to return the GMV of a particular month in a given year using index match (i.e. setting >1 conditions), thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF you have <kbd>Office365</kbd> then `XLOOKUP()` can search from last to first.

```
=XLOOKUP(I2,C8:C13,E8:E13,"",0,-1)
```

Here `[search_mode]` parameter `-1` indicates to search from last to first. If you don't have `Excel365` then you have to provide both year and month to match exact month for the year.

If you always search for current year's month then use `Match()` function like-

```
=INDEX(E8:E13,MATCH(YEAR(TODAY())&I2,B8:B13&C8:C13,0))
```

You may need to enter the formula as array entry with <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the next steps to be done in the following order:

1. Change cells C2:E3 and G3:I3 to be Oct-2020, Nov-2020 ....
2. Change the formula in Row no. 3 to :

> =INDEX($E$8:$E$22,MATCH(C$2,$D$8:$D$22,0))

Make sure that Row no.2 values match values below "Date" title in D column[image]

Comment: Will it work? because cell C2 is Oct-20 while Column D is Oct-2020

Comment: Actually they are both same date but only different in format.

better to keep them same date format or same text value to avoid ambiguity